# I need to put can place on tags on a custom spawn egg in 1.16.4

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I like to design minigames in vanilla on a Realm, and I use a command generator pretty frequently ( https://www.gamergeeks.nz/apps/minecraft/give-command-generator ). I have most of the command I need already, but if someone could send tell me where the adventure mode tag (can place on TNT) goes that would be great.

Command:

```
/give @p skeleton_spawn_egg{EntityTag:
    {HandItems:
      [
        {id:bow,tag:
          {Enchantments:
            [{id:flame,lvl:1}]
          },
          Count:1
        }
      ],
      ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:tnt,Count:1}],
      ArmorDropChances:[0F,0F,0F,0.00F],
      HandDropChances:[0F]
    }
} 1
```

Answer (score 1):

It goes in the root tag, outside `EntityTag`:

```
{
    EntityTag: {
        HandItems: [
            {
                id: "minecraft:bow",
                tag: {
                    Enchantments: [
                        {
                            id: "minecraft:flame",
                            lvl: 1s
                        }
                    ]
                },
                Count: 1b
            }
        ],
        ArmorItems: [
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {
                id: "minecraft:tnt",
                Count:1b
            }
        ],
        ArmorDropChances: [
            0.0f,
            0.0f,
            0.0f,
            0.0f
        ],
        HandDropChances: [
            0.0f,
            0.0f
        ]
    },
    CanPlaceOn:[
        "minecraft:dirt"
    ]
}
```